# Dask error: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, runtime-error, dask

I have read csv file using [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) this way:

```
import dask.dataframe  as dd
train = dd.read_csv('act_train.csv')
```

Then I would like to apply simple logic per row , that works pretty fine in pandas:

```
columns = list(train.columns)

for col in columns[1:]:
    train[col] = train[col].apply(lambda x: x if x == -1 else x.split(' ')[1])
```

Unfortunately, last line of code generates the following error: *Length of values does not match length of index*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Rocketq, can you provide an example that can be easily run by someone without your dataset?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x doesn't contain space character than x.split(' ') will return a list containing single element x.

So, when u are trying to access the second element of x.split(' ') by calling 
x.split(' ')[1]. It will give the error :

"Length of values does not match length of index", as there is no element at index 1 in x.split(' ').

Comment: @Rocketq It will work fine if all x contains space character

Comment: Yes, the point is, that problem is related with something different