# Dask Length of values does not match length of index error

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I encountered a very strange error having to do with assigning a new column to an existing dask dataframe. Given the below minimal example,

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd
from dask import array as da

foo = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'number':list(range(10))}), chunksize=2)
add_me = ["N/A" for _ in range(len(foo.index))]
add_me = da.from_array(add_me, chunks='auto').compute()
```

I'd expect the following to work just fine

```
foo = foo.assign(added=lambda x: add_me[x['number']]).compute()
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

When I compute the dataframe first and then add the column using the same syntax (only then in native pandas), it works just fine:

```
foo = foo.compute()
foo = foo.assign(added=lambda x: add_me[x['number']])
foo
>>>>>     number added
      0     0     N/A
      1     1     N/A
      2     2     N/A
      3     3     N/A
      4     4     N/A
      5     5     N/A
      6     6     N/A
      7     7     N/A
      8     8     N/A
      9     9     N/A
```

Am I missing something here?

I read the following related post ([Dask error: Length of values does not match length of index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829387/dask-error-length-of-values-does-not-match-length-of-index)), but didn't find helpful advice.

Comment: Hi emilaz were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Hey unfortunately not, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the actual operation you are performing is row-wise (does not depend on the values of other rows), then the `dask` version of the code can be refactored to:

```py
foo = foo.map_partitions(lambda df: df.assign(added=lambda x: add_me[x['number']]))
```

Or in a slightly more readable version:

```py
def add_custom(df):
    return df.assign(added=lambda x: add_me[x['number']])

foo = foo.map_partitions(add_custom)
```